# random problem with HttpWebRequest over HTTPS

Tags: c#, apache, .net-3.5, https, httpwebrequest

We have an application using HttpWebRequest to post data to a remote server, over HTTPS (handled by an apache front-end).

Most of time, everything works fine.

From time to time, we have the following exception :

```
    WebException occured SecureChannelFailure ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

But this exception is caught, the application retries a bit later, and everything goes fine again (something must fail in the HTTPS handshake, I don't know what).

Recently, we had a new problem we can't reproduce :

On the web-site side (apache), we have a HTTP 403, with message " Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!? ".

On the .NET client-side, we have a silent crash (or application is stuck without timeout, I can't tell). The only thing we know : it's not a WebException which is correctly handled by the application.
Unfortunately, there's not enough Exception logging around this portion of code, and we cannot easily deploy a new version of the application with System.Net traces for investigation around handshake.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Here is the code :

```
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;

        // set client certificate and server certificate validation callback
        ConfigureWebRequestSecurity(req); 

        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip");
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;

        HttpWebResponse resp = null;
        try
        {
            using (Stream post = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                post.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            Log.Logger.DebugFormat("REST : HTTP Response={0}({1})", (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusCode.ToString());

            if (!resp.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                throw new MOServerErrorException("The server did not respond with status 200 (OK), but with " + resp.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            string m = string.Format("REST : WebException occured {0}", e.Status.ToString());
            throw new MOServerErrorException(m, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (resp != null)
                resp.Close();
        }
```

---

**EDIT** :
Ok, I've managed to reproduce the problem. The thread hangs in GetRequestStream().
Here is the stack :

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(long timeout, bool exitContext) + 0x2f bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) + 0x25 bytes    
>   System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.WaitForCompletion(bool snap) + 0xd3 bytes 
    System.dll!System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckEnqueueRead(byte[] buffer = {byte[4096]}, int offset = 0, int count = 4096, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest request) + 0x194 bytes 
    System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(byte[] buffer = {byte[4096]}, int offset = 0, int count = 4096, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = null) + 0x6d bytes    
    System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = null) + 0x6b bytes   
    System.dll!System.Net.TlsStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) + 0x58 bytes  
    System.dll!System.Net.PooledStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) + 0x1b bytes   
    System.dll!System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = {System.Net.HttpWebRequest}, bool userRetrievedStream = false, bool probeRead = true) + 0x12a bytes   
    System.dll!System.Net.Connection.PollAndRead(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, bool userRetrievedStream) + 0x5a bytes  
    System.dll!System.Net.ConnectStream.PollAndRead(bool userRetrievedStream) + 0x1b bytes  
    System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndWriteHeaders(bool async) + 0xa2 bytes   
    System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteHeadersCallback(System.Net.WebExceptionStatus errorStatus, System.Net.ConnectStream stream = {System.Net.ConnectStream}, bool async) + 0x16 bytes 
    System.dll!System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(bool async) + 0x2d1 bytes  
    System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest() + 0x82 bytes    
    System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetRequestSubmitDone(System.Net.ConnectStream submitStream) + 0xf7 bytes   
    System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteConnection(bool async, System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = {System.Net.HttpWebRequest}) + 0x158 bytes  
    System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(bool async, System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest) + 0x177 bytes    
    System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(bool onSubmitThread, System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = {System.Net.HttpWebRequest}, System.Net.TriState needReConnect = True) + 0x9a bytes  
    System.dll!System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = {System.Net.HttpWebRequest}) + 0x293 bytes   
    System.dll!System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = {System.Net.HttpWebRequest}, string connName = "S>1054081937") + 0x7c bytes    
    System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(System.Net.ServicePoint servicePoint) + 0xf9 bytes   
    System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(out System.Net.TransportContext context = null) + 0x1d3 bytes 
    System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() + 0xe bytes
```

It hangs here, no timeout occurs. Sounds like a bug in the network stack !!

Comment: Additional information : there's a special case in the application where this code is executed by a background thread which *have* a "last chance" exception handler with logging... and no exception was logged ! Our best bet is that the request is stuck, without timeout, but I don't know how this could be possible. Maybe something down the network stack ?

Comment: I've seen responses get stuck when I call `Close()`. I don't know why it happens, and it doesn't happen very often.  I've found that if I do `request.Abort()` followed by `response.Close()`, then it *never* happens. This might be related to high memory usage by the Network instance of svchost.exe, a problem that's plagued me for some time and that I've been unable to find any information about.

Comment: Why cant you enable System.net tracing?  You just have to add a application config file that has the setting enabled. Without that it will be difficult to debug. Or, you can attach windbg.exe to it, and it will stop when the app crashes. You can then debug it as a managed app.

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem with WebException occured SecureChannelFailure ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be [KB980817](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980817)

I didn't manage to install the proposed hotfix (setup goes fine... but System.dll remains unchanged).
As a workaround, I'm using the async version of the API (Begin ...End) and manage a timeout by myself.